# MySQL Workbench unable to restore workspace

Tags: windows-7, mysql, mysql-workbench

Whenever I restart MySQL Workbench I get the following error:

[image]

That error doesn't make any sense to me. I'm able to open `E:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\MySQL` in Explorer, so if I'm able to open that then `E:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\..\` is clearly able to be opened as well.

So why am I getting this error? More importantly, what can I do to get rid of it? Should I uninstall / reinstall MySQL Workbench?

Comment: Why is there a `:` at the end of the 2nd error message?

Comment: I don't know but it's outside of the single quotes so it's my assumption that that's not a part of the path that it's trying to access. My guess: that's just how they coded the error messages. eg. "*Failed to open file '%s': No such file or directory*"

Comment: Is there a full error message in the event logs?

Comment: I'm not seeing anything. I'm doing eventvwr.msc -> Windows Logs -> Application and don't see anything new there. Like I was able to duplicate the problem a minute ago but the last item I'm seeing in there is from a half hour ago..

Comment: It is September 2020 and it is still happening in Workbench 8.0!

Comment: Still actual in 2021. Just a tip for desperate souls: when you experience such "trimmed" messages in error modal, just do a Ctrl + V and then paste into your favorite text editor. This will "unveil" the full message for you at least :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Close the workbench then go to

```
    C:\Users\YOURUSER\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\sql_workspaces
```

and delete all data and directories there.

Your last session will be not restored but the future sessions will.

Comment: Worked for me, that error was becoming annoying!

Comment: If you have multiple connections in your Workbench, you can only delete the directories with the name of the connection causing the issue in case you want to preserve the other workspaces.

Comment: For clarity: `...\sql_workspaces\<connection_name>-<instance>.autosave` is generated as working cache. When workspace is closed `autosave` gets converted to `workspace`. Workspace is restored using `workspace`. When `autosave` instance already exists (conversion to `workspace` failed), a new `autosave` instance is created.

Comment: Shortcut `%AppData%\MySQL\Workbench\sql_workspaces`

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm replying after long time. But I found out a way of getting out of this situation. Note that, I was using Workbench 6.3 and MySQL server 5.7 while writing this answer.

I got this error "Could not read contents of..." when the laptop switched off all of a sudden when I moved the laptop a bit (battery loose connection problem) making Workbench and all applications closing unexpectedly, which is as good as the workbench getting crashed.

If you ever encounter the above error, do not click on either "Ignore" or "Cancel" button until you backup the workspace folder first.
Go to

1. "C:\Users\YOUR.USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\sql_workspaces\YOUR_CONNECTION_NAME". Select proper folder names in your system, wherever I've used capital letters.
   First keep a backup of all the files inside that folder.
2. Open each file in your favorite editor, which is capable of opening non-human readable characters also. (I prefer Notepad++).
3. No matter whether the file is connection_id or whichever the file it is, if you see the file filled with "Null" or any illegal characters, close that file and delete such files These files are the culprit here which makes workbench to show the error.
4. Finally you should end up with only files that has human readable data in them.
5. Now click either on "Cancel" or "Ignore" button, close the connection, try reopening the connection.

But now you can't see the table names in their tabs, instead, you will see whatever the random number those files has got inside the workspace folder.

This is your best shot of restoring auto saved queries. The rest of them are permanently lost.

Thank you.

Comment: Still an issue in 2021, I'm on Workbench 8.0 and Windows 10 Enterprise. Happens after application force close (due to freeze) or as I recently discovered - system crash :) In my case ALL the files appear to be filled with useless `NUL` characters, so no tabs survive in ANY of the connections I had opened, which is very discouraging...

Comment: This works well if I have already tried to reopen Workbench, reopen a connection, and clicked Ignore or Cancel. If I remember, I think the other method (by user Improv) is easier and worked in the past if I did it before attempting to open the connection for the first time after the crash. This is still a problem in 2023, Workbench 8.0.32, Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

I've been having this problem for months on Windows 10. I just wanted to restore my previous session. I tried updating Workbench to the latest version and "Run as administrator". Nothing worked.

Heres how I finally got it to work:

1. Open MySQL Workbench.
2. Right-click on the MySQL Connections pane and select "Open Connection" from the right-click menu.
3. Left click on the MySQL Connections pane as normal. All the old tabs are restored.
4. **Important:** When you reopen MySQL workbench later this same process may need to be followed. I sure hope the bug is fixed in the meantime.

Comment: This doesn't work currently, though I thought it did at one time. Maybe Workbench was changed. Step 2 opens the connection with the "Restore Workspace" error. Step 3 doesn't seem to follow. My attempt doesn't result in restored tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Close the workbench then go to

```
C:\Users\YOURUSER\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\sql_workspaces
```

and look for the [connection name].autosave folder.

Delete the **lock** file.

Reopen workbench.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I renamed a connecteion.
the old name was "new connection"
when I renamed this back to "new connection" the error went away
the workspaces are named according to the connection names